# Connecting to a MySql Database wil standalone windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installshield

I have created a Windows Form Application to write and view a MySQL database.  I installed MySQL to my local computer and placed the database on my company network.  I successfully built a .exe using Install Shield Limited Edition for Visual Studio.  However after I install the app on another computer I can not connect to the DB.  I do not have usernames on this database and want to have the ability for multiple users to access it via this app that I have created.  The line of code I have that accesses my database is below...What do I have to change to make this work?

Thank you

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=XXX";
```

Comment: `datasource=localhost` points to local computer, if you are trying to access the database from another computer, then your connection string should have the IP address or computer name for the machine hosting the database.

Comment: Also see [Allow remote connections for MySQL on Windows](http://techminded.net/blog/allow-remote-connections-for-mysql-on-windows.html)

Comment: I've added my IP address in place of loclahost and can not connect from my own CPU

Comment: did you see the second comment about enabling remote access to MySQL ?

Comment: Yes I changed local source to my IP and used the command GRANT ALL PRIVALEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx' and attempted to install it on another computer...do I have to install MySQL on every computer?

Comment: Did you all for access on port 3306 on the computer where MySQL is installed?  Also, is the application crashing or just not connecting?  The other PCs probably aren't going to have the MySQL DLLs in the global assembly cache.